# Do all polymers contain either carbon or silicon?

Tags: polymers, terminology, carbon-family

Is either carbon or silicon present in every known polymer?

If not, is there a small group of elements that, between them, are present in every known polymer, or can polymers be based on a lot of different elements?

Comment: Not all and answer may depend on what you'd call a polymer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, neither C nor Si have to be present in a polymer.
IUPAC defines [polymer](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/P/P04735.html) simply as

> A substance composed of macromolecules.

In turn, there is no limitations on the elements the [macromolecules](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/M/M03667.html) may consist of.
In fact, there is an extensive class of [inorganic polymers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inorganic_polymer) free of carbon and silicon.